# PHP PDO How to keep just one MYSQL connection

Tags: php, mysql, design-patterns, pdo

I'd like to know a better or best way to initialize PDO mysql connection once and use it. I actually implemented singleton design pattern to PDO and it works just fine, I'm happy with it, but anyway I found a lot of discussions going on stackoverflow about singleton design pattern and how bad it really is, that it's anti-pattern, bad for testing and etc... To be honest I don't know other ways to make the same functionality without using singleton and as long as it works I don't care, the project where I'm using singleton pattern is really small and probably will never be extended. Should I really stop using singleton pattern in PHP everywhere? I would be really happy if someone out here could explain me what are alternatives to singleton pattern if I want let's say to keep the same MYSQL connection in whole application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use singleton database connection in almost all of my applications. By doing this I know that I am always working with the same copy, and not having to mess around with multiple instances.. (When I know it's not needed).

I have written multiple applications and large web services where I have used singletons, and it works like a dream.

When it comes to the database-connection, the only thing I'd imagine you be able to do to keep your database connection shared woul be to simply define it as a variable.. I know this sounds messy, but you simply cannot have one open connection shared among multiple "database"-instances (e.g. if your class name was database).. unless the connection itself was passed as a parameter to the consstructor...

Designing the application without singletons is smart and good way of approaching alot of situations.. but when it comes to database-handling I prefer singletons myself..

Comment: Thank you so much for fast response, yeah somehow I accidentally skipped this solution to create just one instance of class that handles database connection and hold it in variable. I can see how it can get messy but I guess I need to come up with better idea, architecture to make things simple. But from the first thought I think it's not that really bad to create separate file, create an instance of that class then hold that instance in variable and once it's done you simply include that file so other files can access that variable easily... Is it bad approach?

Comment: That's not a bad approach at all. It's probably the most standard thing you'll find around. As long as you keep the connection stored in a variable inside an instance that's accessible in all parts of your application (where you need it, of course) you're good to go, really..